# Silly question on Measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. we have

> (1)  $\mu$ is said to have the property $P_1$ if there is a countable family $\mathcal{C}$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that for every $U\in S$ and every $\epsilon >0$, there is $C\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $C\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\setminus C)<\epsilon$.
>
> (2)  $\mu$ is said to have the property $P_2$ for every $U\in S$ and every $\epsilon >0$, there is a compact set $C\in X$ such that $C\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\setminus C)<\epsilon$
>
> I am getting confused whether $P_1\implies P_2$ or the converse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $P_1\implies P_2$, because $P_1$ guarantees that you can always find a compact set. The converse may fail, because in $P_1$ you want to restrict to a fixed countable family of compacts.